# Errors after installing Wine

Tags: 20.04, wine

Today I installed wine to run a windows software which mostly uses GPU. But after installing wine, when I tried to run that software I got the following errors:

```
ferdous@Ferdous-PC:~$ winecfg

001b:err:ntoskrnl:ZwLoadDriver failed to create driver L"\\Registry\\Machine\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\wineusb": c0000142  
000f:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"wineusb" failed to start: 1114
Wine cannot find the ncurses library (libncurses.so.5).
```

I reinstalled several times, this is the least errors I'm seeing, my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is clean a install. I followed a tutorial & installed the stable wine version.

Answer (score 1):

First fully uninstall wine that exixts on your machine.

`sudo apt-get remove wine --purge`

Then update and upgrade

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt upgrade`

Next enable “multiarch” in the terminal to define thesystem architecture. After that, update  again.

`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

`sudo apt update`

Then install wine

`sudo apt install wine64 wine32`

This seams OK to me. Works perfectly.